# How can I access Holographic remoting for the HoloLens 2 in Unreal Engine 5.1.1 without the Windows Mixed Reality option in Project Settings?

Tags: hololens

I am following the mixed realities team guide to developing for the HoloLens 2 with Unreal Engine. I do not have the "Windows Mixed Reality" option for holographic remoting to my HL2, and I do have all the instructed plugins installed. Can somebody guide me in the right direction?

I followed the guide step by step, making sure IU have the OpenXR and XRToolkit installed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that [Microsoft OpenXR](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/ef8930ca860148c498b46887da196239) is installed and enabled. It is different from the OpenXR plugin that comes with the engine, you can refer to [Upgrading projects in Unreal - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unreal/unreal-porting#openxr-vs-microsoft-openxr) for more information.